# Auto starting home assistant in WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have followed the user documentation for setting up home assistant in wsl: [Home Assistant Installation for Windows](https://www.home-assistant.io/installation/windows/).

I have also used task scheduler and netsh to automatically forward ports on logon in windows 11. When I start wsl, I have to use the commands listed in the link above:

```
sudo -u homeassistant -H -s
cd /srv/homeassistant
python3.8 -m venv .
source bin/activate
hass --verbose
```

What I am after is having the commands above automatically execute on login of wsl, instead of typing it. I have tried to edit the .bashrc file for the user and have had some unexpected results which I will try to summarize as logically as i can.

I have added an if statement in my .bashrc file that reads user input on login, if the input equals a certain phrase, then I want to execute all the above commands. I tried to add just the commands above to my personal (not "homeassistant") user .bashrc, and when I log in, only the first command seems to be executed until I type "exit", and then it seemingly starts the hass server but is the wrong user so it doesnt have my config files and doesnt show my devices in hass.

If I try to add "&" at the end of each command, it will go through the commands but will not return successful and then has an error about hass is not found, because the commands before it failed obviously.

Then I tried to put a wait command after each one because I thought that maybe it was trying to execute to fast, but that didn't solve it either.

So in the end, I am wanting to just login, type a phrase, and if phrase matches with pre-defined phrases, then run the commands above. Any help would sure be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: have solved the issue by adding in my personal .bashrc to login as homeassistant if phrase matches predefined phrase, then in homeassistant .bashrc i added the remaining 4 commands and it works lovely. now i can user terminal preview in windows and just open a new tab and type the phrase and it will start my hass server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's good to hear that you found a workaround, here are a few other ways to do it without modifying your normal startup config:

First, since (per your comment) you have already used Task Scheduler in Windows to add the forwarding rules, you can simply extend this to start hass as well.  Since you already have a `homeassistant` user with the startup commands in that user's `~/.bashrc`, just create a new Login task to run `wsl -u homeassistant -e bash -lic "true"`.  That will start up a WSL instance under the `homeassistant` user, which will run the commands in that user's `.bashrc`.

There's also a new feature in WSL in Windows 11 (if you can upgrade) that allows you to run commands when your WSL instance starts.  The easiest way to take advantage of this would be to:

- Move the last 4 lines (the same as you put in `.bashrc`) into a new script under `/home/homeassisant/hass_start.sh`:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/bash
  cd /srv/homeassistant
  python3.8 -m venv .
  source bin/activate
  hass --verbose
  ```
- Make that script executable (`chmod +x hass_start.sh`)
- Edit or create (as `sudo`) `/etc/wsl.conf` with the following contents:

  ```
  [boot]
  command="sudo -u homeassistant -H /home/homeassistant/hass_start.sh"
  ```

Comment: thanks. and actually why not just launch wsl from task scheduler with ```wsl sudo -u homeassistant -H -s ~homeassistant/hass_start.sh```? i did and so far it seems to work great. thanks.

Comment: @james28909 Yes, on Windows 10 that will have the same effect.  I was just building off the way that you had set it up already.  On Windows 11, the nice thing about the `[boot]` config is that it will ensure that Home Assistant restarts automatically even if you have to restart WSL with a full reboot (e.g. `wsl --shutdown` or `wsl --terminate <distro>`.